# SUMO traffic: using JTRROUTER e flow definition

Tags: xml, sumo

I have a net.xml file and i like to create a rou.xml using JTRROUTER. 
I have yet exctract a con.xml file from net.xml file using `netconvert -s *.net.xml --plain-output-prefix plain` then generate a turndefs.xml:

```
sumo_home/tools/turn-defs/generateTurnDefs.py --connections-file connections.con.xml --turn-definitions-file output.turndefs.xml
```

Now, for using

`jtrrouter --flow-files=<flow_defs> --turn-ratio-files=<turn_definitions> --net-file=<sumo_net> \ --output-file=MySUMORoutes.rou.xml --begin <uint> --end <uint>`

I need a flow definiton, how can generate it? I must create a txt file with just `<flow id="0" from="A" begin="0" end="3600" probability="0.5"/>`?

How to save it?
What  "A" means?

Comment: no one? please.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume your command is correct, you can store the result in a file by using the option `-o YOURFILENAME.rou.xml`.

The A in your example flow is the edge where the flow starts. All the details for flows are written in the [SUMO wiki](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes#Repeated_vehicles_.28Flows.29)